What properties of the fundamental group functor are needed to uniquely determine it upto natural isomorphism?
Consider a functor from pointed topological spaces to groups, which
evaluates the same on homotopically equivalent topological spaces and also on homotopic continuous functions.
What additional properties do I need for this to be the fundamental group functor?
Note: I am thinking of something along the lines of Jamie Banks's answer to What's an intuitive way to think about the determinant?. Presuming we know from where to where the map is, plus some additional properties of the map, then we can actually pin down the map and say how it evaluates on the things it takes as inputs.

Ronnie Brown spent his career arguing that there is a Fundamental Groupoid rather than group. I suggest looking in his work for an Answer to your Question (which certainly does not deserve down-votes).

You may need to restrict to some nice category like that of CW complexes. I suspect a characterization analogous to Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms may exist but I have never encountered one. Few properties you probably want to include is homotopy invariance, Seifert-van Kampen and evaluation at $S^1$. Whether this is sufficient, I have no idea.

@Wojowu : the three things you indicate are indeed sufficient on the category of CW-complexes, though probably not in general

Here is a relevant paper: AXIOMATIC APPROACH TO THE HOMOTOPY GROUPS

If you consider the codomain as 2 category $2Grpd$ instead of $Grp$, then probably you can determine the fundamental groupoid functor by the universal property that it's the terminal object in the 2 category of costacks on sites generating from some nice topological spaces, as shown in this paper.

$\newcommand{\Top}{\mathrm{Top}} \newcommand{\Grp}{\mathrm{Grp}} \newcommand{\Set}{\mathrm{Set}} \newcommand{\pinch}{\mathrm{pinch}}$
This is kind of an open-ended question but a possible answer was given by Wojowu in the comments: any functor $f:\Top_*\to \Grp$ which sends the point to $1$, the circle to $\mathbb Z$, is homotopy invariant and satisfies the Van Kampen theorem is isomorphic to $\pi_1$, at least when restricted to pointed connected finite CW-complexes (without the value at the point, the functor could be constant with value $\mathbb Z$).
The argument is as follows. First, $f$ is homotopy invariant and hence factors through the homotopy category of pointed topological spaces. By the Yoneda lemma applied in that category, it follows that picking out $1\in \mathbb Z\cong f(S^1)$ induces a map of set-valued functors $h:\pi_1\to f$. I claim that this is a group morphism. This is not completely trivial, and I will explain that later. In fact, it's not completely true: either $h$, or the morphism corresponding to $-1\in f(S^1)$ is a group morphism. This is what I will prove later.
For now, let's take it for granted. On $S^1$,  $h$ sends $1\in\mathbb Z\cong \pi_1(S^1)$ to $1\in \mathbb Z\cong f(S^1)$ (or $-1$) and hence is an isomorphism. On disks, homotopy invariance shows that both $f$ and $\pi_1$ are trivial, and hence also on higher dimensional spheres by van Kampen. Since general finite pointed connected finite CW-complexes are built out of spheres by pushouts to which one can apply van Kampen, it follows that $h$ is an isomorphism on all of them, as was claimed.
To get to infinite CW complexes, one will need some kind of finitary-ness properties of $f$, such as the fact that it preserves filtered (homotopy) colimits/unions of CW-complexes. Then the same argument will work. To get beyond connectedness, one might simply impose it by asking that for any $(X,x)$, the inclusion of the component at $x$ induces an isomorphism on $f$.
It seems difficult to say anything for general topological spaces if you do not assume that the functor is invariant under weak homotopy equivalences.
Finally, the statement about $h:\pi_1\to f$ being a group map. Recall that the group structure on $\pi_1$ is induced by the cogroup (up to homotopy) structure on $S^1$. Unwinding in terms of the Yoneda lemma what it means for $h$ to be a group morphism, we find that it  corresponds to the statement that the following two elements agree in $f(S^1\vee S^1)$: $f(i_a)(1) f(i_b)(1)$ and $f(\pinch)(1)$ where $i_a, i_b: S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ are the two inclusions, and $\pinch: S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ is the pinch map defining the multiplication on $\pi_1$.
By van Kampen, however, the map induced by $i_a$ and $i_b$, $f(S^1)*f(S^1)\to f(S^1\vee S^1)$ is an isomorphism, and so the comultiplication map on $S^1$ induces a cogroup structure on $f(S^1)$ in $\Grp$. The following is the key nontrivial statement:
Lemma: There are exactly two cogroup structures on $\mathbb Z$, corresponding to the morphisms $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_a * \mathbb Z_b, 1\mapsto 1_a * 1_b$ and $1_b * 1_a$.
This lemma is a tedious if elementary verification with free words - it corresponds to the statement that the forgetful functor $\Grp\to \Set$ has exactly two group structures: the obvious one, or the opposite multiplication one. It was proved by Kan, and is also recorded in Comultiplications on Free Groups and Wedges of Circles (with other fun stuff about comultiplications in general)
From this, it is clear that either $f(i_a)(1) f(i_b)(1) = f(\pinch)(1)$, or $f(i_b)(1) f(i_a)(1) = f(\pinch)(1)$. In the latter case, picking $-1$ in place of $1$ in the definition of $h$ reduces us to the previous case, so that $h$ is indeed a group morphism, as was to be shown.
